# Get Javascript value in array for Google map, heatmap, after getting the values from xml file

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, global-variables, heatmap

I need to create a heatmap layer in Google map using data from an xml file.
My xml file have latitude and longitude which I need to put in an array call taxiData[].

I have been able to console.log the latitudes and longitudes that i am getting from the xml.

However, if i log it outside, i loss the values. My lat and lng have been declared as global.

How do I get it in the array taxiData so that i can use it when initializing the map?

My code is as follows

```
 var map, pointarray, heatmap;
        var lat, lng;
        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                    new XMLHttpRequest;
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }
        function doNothing() {
        }
        downloadUrl("locations_xml.php", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
                lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
                console.log(lat, lng);
            }
        });
   //    console.log(lat, lng); --> does not work

   //I want to add the above lat and lng to this array below instead of the static values;

        var taxiData = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(-20.037720, 57.602348),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-20.044815, 57.570076),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-20.047396, 57.632561),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-20.055780, 57.600288),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-20.310350, 57.436180),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-20.339325, 57.478752)
        ];
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.037720, 57.602348),
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                    mapOptions);
            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);
            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray
            });
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        }
        function changeGradient() {
            var gradient = [
                'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
                'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
                'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
                'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
                'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
                'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
            ]
            heatmap.set('gradient', heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `taxiData` as a global array

```
var map, pointarray, heatmap;
var lat, lng;
var taxiData = [];
```

And then set it in function `downloadUrl()`:

```
    downloadUrl("locations_xml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
            lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));

            taxiData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
            console.log(lat, lng);
        }
    });
```

And delete static array.

**Update:** Because `downloadUrl()` call is asynchronous, `taxiData` is not available in function `initialize`. Function `initialize()` is started before callback finishes with collecting data. One possible solution is to comment out `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` and call function `initialize()` at the end of callback function after `for loop`.

Comment: It appears like the global variable taxiData is not working.

When I am passing value to the array taxiData inside the function downloadUrl, the array values are not being maintained outside.

Comment: The problem is in asynchronous call of `downloadUrl()`. Function `initialize()` is started before callback finishes with collecting data. One possible solution is to comment out `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` and call function `initialize()` at the end of callback function after `for loop`. I cannot test it that because I have no such environment.